# Raku control statement to make numeric strings interpreted as numeric

Tags: raku

I have a large hash of arrays,

`%qual<discordant>` (~approx. 13199 values like '88.23', '99.23', etc.

which ranges from 88-100, and are read in from text files,

and when I print `%qual<discordant>.min` and `%qual<discordant>.max` I can see the values are clearly wrong.

I can fix this by changing how the data is read in from the text files:

`%qual{$type}.push: @line[5]`

to

`%qual{$type}.push: @line[5].Num`

but this wasn't intuitive, this took me a few minutes to figure out why Raku/Perl6 was giving clearly incorrect answers at first.  It would have been very easy to miss this error.  In perl5, the default behavior would be to treat these strings like numbers anyway.

There should be some control statement to make this the default behavior, how can I do this?

Comment: How does `@line` get filled?

Comment: `@line` is filled from text files, `my @line = $line.split(/\s+/)`

Comment: `my @line = $line.words` will then be faster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem / feature is really that in Raku when you read lines from a file, they become strings (aka objects of type `Str`).  If you call `.min` and `.max` on an array of `Str` objects, then string semantics will be used to determine whether something is bigger or smaller.

There **are** special values in Raku that act like values in Perl.  In Raku these are called "[allomorphs](https://docs.perl6.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Allomorph)".  They are `Str`, but also `Num`, or `Rat`, or `Int`, or `Complex`.

The syntax for creating an appropriate allomorph for a string in `$_` is `<< $_ >>`.  So if you change the line that reads the words to:

```
my @line = $line.words.map: { << $_ >> }
```

then the values in `@line` will either be `Str`, or `IntStr` or `RatStr`.  Which should make `.min` and `.max` work like you expect.

However, if you are sure that only the 5th element of `@line` is going to be numeric, then it is probably more efficient to convert the `Str` to a number before pushing to the array.  A shorter syntax for that would be to prefix a `+`:

```
%qual{$type}.push: +@line[5]
```

Although you might find that too line-noisy.

UPDATE: I had forgotten that there's actually a sub called `val` that takes an `Str` and creates an appropriate allomorph of it (or returns the original `Str`).  So the code for creating `@line` could be written as:

```
my @line = $line.words>>.&val
```

Comment: Often I like to use `.Numeric` instead of `+` in part to avoid too many symbols all in a row, but also because it jumps out a bit more to say "Hey, I need this as a number", the `+` is small enough it can get lost in the shuffle (ditto for `~` vs `.Str`).

Comment: I think that the default behavior in Raku should be similar to Perl, i.e. basically everything is an allomorph, it's easier and more intuitive.  I think the default should be to consider strings like `83.44` as numeric

Comment: Creating allomorphs is cumbersome in Raku, as it requires work to be done to be able to create the right allomorph type.  This contrary to Perl, where that work gets done when the variable is actually used in a numeric context because Perl doesn't have any explicit typing.  So not creating everything as an allomorph is not only a very well thought out design decision, there are also performance reasons to not do that.

Comment: fwiw i think raku should “do what i mean” ... << $_ >> is very noisy ... so, regardless of speed, please can we have a method, let’s say $line.allo for this? (yes i know i can write one!)

Comment: `val($line)` would not do it for you?

Comment: reads doc, dang it already there - that’s what i love about raku

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen your suggestions work greatly, thanks :) I was hoping for a global setting change, but this works too